# Email not sent via nodemailer

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nodemailer, json-server

I am developing authentication Api with Express and json-server. I am trying to send a verification email when the user signed up. After a new user is created in a database then an email should be sent but is not.

```
// Create new user
  const newUser: User = {
    id: uuidv4(),
    email: user.email,
    name: String(user.name),
    passwordHash: await bcrypt.hash(String(user.password), 10),
  };

  await Api.post(USERS_URL, newUser); << if i delete this line then an email is sent

  // Sent verification link
  const emailToken = Auth.generateToken(user.email);
  const message = `Click the link below to verify your email\nhttp://localhost:4000/verifyEmail/${newUser.id}/${emailToken}`;
  try {
    await Email.send(user.email, 'Verify your email', message);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send('Email not sent');
  }

  return res.status(OK).send('Email sent');
```

Api module

```
export class Api {
  private static baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001';

  private static getUrl(url: string, id?: string | number) {
    return id ? this.baseUrl + url + `/${id}` : this.baseUrl + url;
  }

  private static responseHandler(response: AxiosResponse) {
    return response.data;
  }

  static async post(url: string, data: any) {
    const response = await Axios.post(this.getUrl(url), data);
    return this.responseHandler(response);
  }
}
```

and Email module

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

export const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'fake@gmail.com',
    pass: 'fake',
  },
});

export class Email {
  static async send(to: string, subject: string, text: string) {
    return transporter.sendMail({
      from: 'fake',
      to,
      subject,
      text,
    });
  }
}
```

If I put the line with posting the user to a database after sending the email it also works but I want to do it after the user is created

I tried everything and now I'm stuck

Comment: I am new at this too, but this line await Api.post(USERS_URL, newUser) is newUser is callback? if it is, is not it executed after  post Api? another question, you make a new user hard coded?

Comment: try to wrap the entire code in the try-catch block, and console the error in the catch block, I am sure there will be an error in Api.post() method.

Comment: @KickButtowski newUser is an object above that line and it is dynamically created

Comment: @NeerajKumar I tried it and nothing happened, no error or email was sent

Comment: It seems my questions except new User part didn't make sense?